# How to install Xpdf on Centos 5.5

Tags: centos, centos-5, xpdf

I'd like to install xPDF on a CentOS 5.5 server. No GUI, I really just need the console apps.

Can anyone give me a brief guide?

Comment: For CentOS 6.7 and later versions of CentOS (including CentOS 7), several PDF command line utilities are provided by the *poppler-utils* package from the default CentOS repositories. This package contains command line utilities for getting information of PDF documents, converting them to other formats, or manipulating them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using EPEL I just downloaded the latest version from the Xpdf website.

Then:

1. I extracted it with `tar -xzvf xpdf_vxxxx.tar.gz`.
2. `cd xpdf_vxxxxx`
3. `./configure` and it warned me that I was missing FreeType and a couple of other libraries, but since I only wanted the console apps anyway I ignored that message.
4. `make`  (more random warning messages)
5. `make install`

Then I could just run `pdftotext` and the rest of them.

Answer (score 4):

Add [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) then use `yum` to install it.

> Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (or EPEL) is a Fedora Special Interest Group that creates, maintains, and manages a high quality set of additional packages for Enterprise Linux, including, but not limited to, Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL),CentOS and Scientific Linux (SL).
>
> EPEL packages are usually based on their Fedora counterparts and will never conflict with or replace packages in the base Enterprise Linux distributions. EPEL uses much of the same infrastructure as Fedora, including buildsystem, bugzilla instance, updates manager, mirror manager and more.